# Complicated jsonData

Tags: android, arrays, json

Here is my json

```
{
    "columns": [
        "logoFileName",
        "logoFileName1",
        "companyEventIDUnique",
        "Date",
        "Event",
        "soldOut",
        "companyEventGroupDescription",
        "eventImageFileName",
        "teamsImagePath"
    ],
    "rows": [
        [
            "RoyalChallengersBangalore11.png",
            "SH11.png",
            14,
            "Monday, 13 Apr 2015, 8:00PM",
            "Royal Challengers Bangalore Vs Sunrisers Hyderabad ",
            0,
            "RCB Home Games 2015",
            "rcb-srh.png",
            "images/upload/team/"
        ],
        [
            "RoyalChallengersBangalore11.png",
            "MumbaiIndiansLogo.png",
            15,
            "Sunday, 19 Apr 2015, 8:00PM",
            "Royal Challengers Bangalore Vs Mumbai Indians ",
            0,
            "RCB Home Games 2015",
            "rcb-mi.png",
            "images/upload/team/"
        ],
        [
            "RoyalChallengersBangalore11.png",
            "ChennaiSuperKingsLogo11.png",
            16,
            "Wednesday, 22 Apr 2015, 8:00PM",
            "Royal Challengers Bangalore Vs Chennai Super Kings ",
            0,
            "RCB Home Games 2015",
            "rcb-csk.png",
            "images/upload/team/"
        ],
        [
            "RoyalChallengersBangalore11.png",
            "RajasthanRoyalsLogo11.png",
            17,
            "Wednesday, 29 Apr 2015, 8:00PM",
            "Royal Challengers Bangalore Vs Rajasthan Royals ",
            0,
            "RCB Home Games 2015",
            "rcb-rr.png",
            "images/upload/team/"
        ],
        [
            "RoyalChallengersBangalore11.png",
            "KKR_logo.png",
            18,
            "Saturday, 02 May 2015, 4:00PM",
            "Royal Challengers Bangalore Vs Kolkata Knight Riders ",
            0,
            "RCB Home Games 2015",
            "rcb-kkr.png",
            "images/upload/team/"
        ],
        [
            "RoyalChallengersBangalore11.png",
            "KingsXIPunjabLogo11.png",
            19,
            "Wednesday, 06 May 2015, 8:00PM",
            "Royal Challengers Bangalore Vs Kings XI Punjab ",
            0,
            "RCB Home Games 2015",
            "rcb-kxip.png",
            "images/upload/team/"
        ],
        [
            "RoyalChallengersBangalore11.png",
            "DelhiDaredevilsLogo12.png",
            20,
            "Sunday, 17 May 2015, 4:00PM",
            "Royal Challengers Bangalore Vs Delhi DareDevils ",
            0,
            "RCB Home Games 2015",
            "rcb-dd.png",
            "images/upload/team/"
        ]
    ]
}
```

And below is my POJO i cant parse the above data

public class EventHandler {

```
public String logoFileName;
public String logoFileName1;
public int companyEventIDUnique;
public String Date;
public String Event;
public int soldOut;
public String companyEventGroupDescription;
public String eventImageFileName;
public String teamsImagePath;

public EventHandler() {

}

public EventHandler(String logoFileName, String logoFileName1,
        int companyEventIDUnique, String Date, String Event, int soldOut,
        String companyEventGroupDescription, String eventImageFileName,
        String teamsImagePath) {

    this.logoFileName = logoFileName;
    this.logoFileName1 = logoFileName1;
    this.companyEventIDUnique = companyEventIDUnique;
    this.companyEventGroupDescription = companyEventGroupDescription;
    this.eventImageFileName = eventImageFileName;
    this.teamsImagePath = teamsImagePath;

}

public String getLogoFileName() {
    return logoFileName;
}

public void setLogoFileName(String logoFileName) {
    this.logoFileName = logoFileName;
}

public String getLogoFileName1() {
    return logoFileName1;
}

public void setLogoFileName1(String logoFileName1) {
    this.logoFileName1 = logoFileName1;
}

public int getCompanyEventIDUnique() {
    return companyEventIDUnique;
}

public void setCompanyEventIDUnique(int companyEventIDUnique) {
    this.companyEventIDUnique = companyEventIDUnique;
}

public String getDate() {
    return Date;
}

public void setDate(String date) {
    Date = date;
}

public String getEvent() {
    return Event;
}

public void setEvent(String event) {
    Event = event;
}

public int getSoldOut() {
    return soldOut;
}

public void setSoldOut(int soldOut) {
    this.soldOut = soldOut;
}

public String getCompanyEventGroupDescription() {
    return companyEventGroupDescription;
}

public void setCompanyEventGroupDescription(
        String companyEventGroupDescription) {
    this.companyEventGroupDescription = companyEventGroupDescription;
}

public String getEventImageFileName() {
    return eventImageFileName;
}

public void setEventImageFileName(String eventImageFileName) {
    this.eventImageFileName = eventImageFileName;
}

public String getTeamsImagePath() {
    return teamsImagePath;
}

public void setTeamsImagePath(String teamsImagePath) {
    this.teamsImagePath = teamsImagePath;
}
```

}

Comment: use some json viewer to get a better picture

Comment: Any error log, stacktrace or clue?

Comment: No error logs i cant parse the data i m confused how to use key value pair in this kind of json array

Comment: i checked in json lint it says as a valid json

Answer (score 0):

The json string you gave isn't json.Json must be Key-value pair.refer this doc.Hope it will help.
[Introducing JSON](http://json.org/)

it should be like

```
{
"key": [
    {
        "key": "value"
    },
    {
        "key": "value"
    }
]
}
```

Comment: Ya it is in key value pair.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting data in  string then you can parse it like this.

```
JsonObject obj = new JsonObject(urString)

jsonArray a1 = obj.getJsonArray("columns");

for(i=0; i<a1.length();i++){
// get all String here

}

jsonArray a2 = obj.getJsonArray("row");

for(i=0; i<a2.length();i++){

jsonArray a3 = a2.getJsonArray("i");

for(i=0; i<a3.length();i++){
//find all String here;

}


}
```

Comment: jsonArray a3 = a2.getJsonArray("i");

for(i=0; i<a3.length();i++){
//find all String here; what does the above code refer to? especially "i"

Answer (score 0):

```
    JSONObject one = new JSONObject(json);
    JSONArray columns = one.getJSONArray("columns");
    for (int i = 0; i < columns.length(); i++)
    {
        String str = columns.getString(i);
        System.out.println("Colums Strings : " + str);
    }
    JSONArray rows = one.getJSONArray("rows");
    for (int i = 0; i < rows.length(); i++)
    {
        JSONArray array = rows.getJSONArray(i);
        for (int j = 0; j < array.length(); j++)
        {
            String str1 = array.getString(j);
            System.out.println("Rows Strings : " + str1);
        }
    }
```

Comment: If i use str1 to print then only last value will be printing, how can i print all the values inside rows json?